# What RxJS operation should I use in getting data from an observable and pushing it to an array?

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, declarative

I'm trying to simulate an http request that supports pagination. For now, this request only returns a number. A parameter of the get request is the page number used in the database.

To be simpler, consider the function getData that returns an observable that returns the page number.

```
  getData(page:number):Observable<number>{
    return new Observable<number>(observer => {
      observer.next(page)
    })
  }
```

Inside my ngOnInit, I declared:

```
data$!:Observer<number>
page:number = 0
ngOnInit():void{
    this.data$ = this.getData(page).pipe(
        //RxJS opeartor so that the data:number received will be converted to an array
    )
}
```

I am also trying to code declaratively/reactively by avoiding subscribe() method. So my approach in the template is something like

`<div *ngFor="let data of data$ | async"> {{data}} </div>`

Lastly, to simulate the "load more" feature, I added `<button (click)="loadMore()">Load More</button>` in the template. And in the component,

```
loadMore():void{
    this.data$ = this.getData(++this.page).pipe(
        //I want to know what should be the RxJS operator that I should use here so that the data<number> that is emitted from the observable, will be appended to this.data$.
    )
}
```

So if I clicked the Load More button 3 times, my template should display

```
0
1
2
```

I am open for other approaches as long as it does not use subscribe().
Thank you!

Comment: The output should be 0 1 2 3 ***

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a subscribe method to work with Observable. I think the easiest way is to use subscribe.
Here's an example:

```
    data: any;
    
    loadMore(): void {
      this.getData(++this.page)
        .subscribe(d => {
           this.data = d;
        });
    }
```

Look all the changes that I did first. Check the data variable is now type any, because I don't know what is your data response type.
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This works with some modifications. To be specific, this.data = d; -> this.data = [...this.data, d]

However, I read that it is not a good practice to use subscribe() since it is necessary to unsubscribe and there are cases that it is tedious? Correct me if I'm wrong.
So I'm trying to practice reactive/declarative approach.

Comment: Glad to know that worked for you :)

Comment: I have edited my comment

Comment: You can use subscribe. It is more easier to use...

Answer (score 0):

In rxjs the standard operator to convert observable data is [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/map).

usage is simple, and similar to `Array.map`:

```
loadMore():void{
    this.data$ = this.getData(++this.page).pipe(
      map(dataIn => ({ dataIn, page: this.page }))
    )
}
```

As you pointed out, it is not good practice to subscribe to observables from the component (it might lead you into the [memory-leak](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject) trap).

Instead of subscribing you should return an observable (or set a variable with the observable as you did) and use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) from the views to extract its values (it subscribes/uinsubscrives as necessary, which voids the issues):

```
<div>{{ (data$ | async)?.page }}</div>
```

Comment: What I want to do is to append dataIn with the values returned by the previous dataIn. Note that dataIn is just a number and not an array. What I want is from this number, I will generate an array, and with the consecutive dataIn that I will receive, I will append this to that array.

Comment: if you could build a minimum reproducible error in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) I might be able help further. I have a felling what you would be after is a [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) to hold the data for you